# TIBCO EMS set queue exclusive property programmatically

Tags: tibco, ems

How can I set the exclusive/non-exclusive property of a tibco queue programmatically?  I want to be able to set the queue as non-exclusive when I crate it in my application.

For example, if I use the following code to craete the queue:

```
QueueConnectionFactory factory = new TIBCO.EMS.QueueConnectionFactory(serverUrl);

QueueConnection connection = factory.CreateQueueConnection(userName, password);

QueueSession session = connection.CreateQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

TIBCO.EMS.Queue queue = session.CreateQueue(queueName);
```

How can I set the queue's properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the TibjmsAdmin API to do that. The JavaDoc of the API can be found [here](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise_message_service/8.1.0/doc/html/tib_ems_api_reference/api/javadoc/index.html)

Then try this:

```
TibjmsAdmin jmsAdmin = new TibjmsAdmin("tcp://localhost:7222", "admin", "admin");
QueueInfo qi = jmsAdmin.getQueue("my.queue");
qi.setExclusive(true);
```

HTH,

Hendrik

Comment: Thanks very much for that, I will need to find the assebly for .Net but at least I know what to look for.